# Best way to delete large amount of files by date

Tags: linux, files, storage

So, I have a folder with alot of files, they are generated by second and need to be kept in I only can delete them after 90 days, so as you may guess, I would generate tons of files and then after the 90 days I'm able to delete those files that is older than 90 days. 
But, I'm stuck in the part where I search for those files, since I have alot, the system complains that the list is too large and thus I can't remove them.

What is the best solution so I can pass this? The file names are in timestamp mode, so I could start by it, but I want to make sure all files are deleted after some time....

I have tried these methods

```
rm -rf *
find /path/to/files/ -type f -name '*.ts' -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;
```

I have also managed to create a script to delete by filename, but with this method I have no guarantee that all the files are deleted.

Comment: What methods have you tried that the system complains about?

Comment: Since I'm still developing this, yesterday I generated about 5 days of files and want to erase them, I just did a rm -rf * and the system yelled at me.

Comment: The problem is not only deleting them....think ahead, and create a directory structure YEAR/MONTH/DATE/HOUR automatically, it will be easier to manage.

Comment: But I also tryied the find method, wich wasn't effective either.

Comment: Please don't ever do `rm -rf *`.  You should always be as specific as possible when removing files with globbing.  `rm -- ./*` would be better for you, no need for `-r` as you want to remove files not directories, and you should only use `-f` if you have to.

Comment: When you say several methods weren't effective, please provide more detail.  [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/414516/edit) your question to include exactly the command you issued and any error messages or other relevant output produced.

Comment: Note that the `find` command is intended to delete files older than 90 days (`-mtime +90`), while your comment indicates you created all the files yesterday.  To test this command, you'd need to ensure there were files more than 90 days old or none will get deleted.  Set the modification and access times on the file to a past date with `touch`, _e.g._ `touch -d "Aug 3, 2017" oldfile`.

Comment: The complaint about too many files is from `rm -rf *` (shell error message). That won't happen with the *find* command. But replace `-exec rm {} \;` with `-delete`. It's much faster (no separate *rm* process per file).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the files are not modified after initial creation, you could delete if they have not been modified in over 90 days:

```
find /path/to/folder ! -type d -mtime +90 -delete
```

or

```
find /path/to/folder ! -type d -mtime +90 -exec rm -f {} +
```

(for versions of `find` which do not support the `-delete` action).

As a matter of safety, you should use a non-destructive version of this command first and ensure it will delete exactly what you want deleted, especially if you intend to automate this action via `cron` or similar, *e.g.*:

```
find /path/to/folder ! -type d -mtime +90 -print
```

Note that `-mtime +90` checks the *modification time* of the files and returns *true* if the age, rounded down to an integer number of days (86400 second units) is *strictly* greater than 90, so matches on files that have been last-modified 91 days ago or earlier.

Comment: +1 for non-destructive

Comment: If you'd like to see the files that match before you actually delete them, you can switch the `-delete` flag to be `-print` to view the files that will be removed -- like a dry run.

Comment: Is this recursive (subfolders included)?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author or *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

With *rawhide* (*rh*) you can do it like this:

```
rh -UUU /path/to/files 'f && "*.ts" && old(90*days)'
```

`-UUU` unlinks/deletes/removes matching files.

`/path/to/files` is a search path.

The rest is the search criteria.

`f` matches regular files.

`"*.ts"` matches files whose names end with `.ts`.

`old(90*days)` matches files last modified at least 90 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, if you need to delete directories, you can use the option `-maxdepth`.

Preview the things that you are going to delete:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -print
```

Remove them all:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} +
```